# I am having issue with a Silverlight's font

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have an application, which does XAML over same pattern.
I need know size characters drawn in Silverlight.
I have used for this MeasureCharacterRanges.

```
Region[] partRegions = tempGraphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(t.Text, font, textRect, stringFormat);
```

But many characters were drawn in Silverlight another (for example japanese characters).
How can I make something similar to my code?
Thanx in advance for the helping hand.